# Как правильно написать PHPUnit(Laravel) для запроса внешнего АПИ и сохранения?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Всем привет. Есть такой код. Хочу написать Unit тесты. Но не знаю как именно это протестировать, поделитесь советом

```
class Kodik
{
    /**
     * Import genres
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function importGenres(): void
    {
        $response = Http::kodik()->get('genres', [
            'token' => config('services.kodik.token'),
            'types' => 'anime,anime-serial',
            'genres_type' => 'shikimori',
        ])->object();

        $genres = $response->results;

        foreach ($genres as $genre) {
            Genre::firstOrCreate([
                'name' => Str::ucfirst(trim($genre->title)),
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#testing
Мокаете ответ от внешнего источника и с помощью нужных asserts проверяете результат.